# FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap' not found while trying to Archive a react native project on XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When  I am trying a React native project on the IOS simulator it works fine. But when try to Archive the project to upload to the App Store, Xcode throws an error saying

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/MyMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<coolapp>-gsdebkxdyslzmjaypmxjdztvchbl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/coolapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap' not found
```

When it is clearly there in the project.
I have tried all the solutions posted on this GitHub thread, but none of those work.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/780

#### My Environment

- `react-native: 0.63.2`
- `react-native-fbsdk: ^3.0.0`
- Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)

Also tried on `fbsdk 2.0.0` and code 11.0+ still the same issue.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. make sure you open the .xcworkspace file and not .xcproject
2. make sure all min iOS versions are the same across your Target, Project and Podfile
3. clean project and rebuild

It might help

Comment: Yes, i have noticed the problem was with pod file and product building settings.

Comment: what exactly you guys changed? in pod file I can't find iOS version. RN 0.65.1

Comment: @Lasharela, in the Podfile, search the min ios version listed in the line "platform :ios, '11.0'" (taken from my Podfile).
Then in Xcode, go to the General tab and look at the value under "Deployment info" (I'm using Xcode 13.0 so it might vary).
Make sure to change it to what's shown on your Podfile.
Also make sure to change it under both "Project" and "Targets"

Comment: Please note that opening the xcworkspace must be done from the Finder by double clicking on it, and not from Xcode Open menu item (which will just open the file, and not allow you to build...)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue because I was importing FBSDK at wrong place in AppDelegate.m

Point is you must import before `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` Here is the correct way:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h" <-- IMPORT HERE! -->

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
<--- DO NOT IMPORT BELOW --->
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
```

Comment: Ty beka, but the problem was conflict with the pod file

Answer (score 0):

By any chance you opened on Xcode .xcodeproj file instead of .xcworkspace file?

Comment: First sentence of the accepted answer: `make sure you open the .xcworkspace file and not .xcproject`